# Typescript: Sync/Async with require and import

Tags: node.js, typescript, asynchronous, require, webdriver-io

I use `browser.waitUntil` for waiting for a print job to finish:

```
browser.waitUntil(() => fileAdapter.exists(pathToDirectory, filename));
```

where `fileAdapter.exists` returns a `Promise<boolean>`. Now the strange thing is that when I import the `fileAdapter` with `require` everything works fine. However, when I use the recommended `import` statement, I get a Sonar warning because `waitUntil` expects a boolean value while getting a Promise instead. I read that the `require` keyword imports in a synchronous way while `import` does not. So that is the reason for the error I suppose. But I didn't find any proper explanation of the mechanism, neither a way to achieve the same with the `import` statement.

Comment: Are you using sync mode or [async mode](https://webdriver.io/docs/sync-vs-async#async-mode)? It looks like [`waitUntil`](https://webdriver.io/docs/api/browser/waitUntil/) supports both, and in async mode it handles promises. Perhaps Sonar doesn't know you're using async mode (or doesn't know `waitUntil` supports it). (Or the code doesn't actually work, and `waitUntil` just always believes the job is finished and you've been lucky with timing. :-) )

Comment: @T.J.Crowder  I start my test case with mocha `test('MyTest', function () {...})`, so I suppose it is synchronous.